# Postman/Chrome Developer Tools: On trying to place break point - break points get deactivated

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, postman

I have used the debugger in my Chrome Tests (js) script so that the Chrome Dev Tools get acivated:

- add debugger statement in your js tests
- right click anywhere on postman window and select inspect option
- send your request - this brings up the chrome dev tools extension ide and pauses at the debugger statement
- enable breakpoint placement by clicking on activate/deactivate breakpoints button [image: Deactivetd] [image: tooltip] [image: Activated]

Now, I noticed that on trying to add a break point it again gets disabled.

Any idea on how to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a complete uninstall of chrome as well as the native app.

Installed back again and this worked.

But this seems to be an issue on postman end itself.

Comment: This does not work for me in Postman v7.14, using the packaged app.  Do you know what's needed now?

Comment: AH, thanks.  My suspicion is that you can't actually get the google dev console for the main app any more...  So, this might be an argument for the Chrome extension?  Does setting breakpoints work there?